# Fragment Open with Keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin

Have one fragment with edittext at the top

When I open that fragment **KeyBoard should automatically open**

To achieve this I am showing the KeyBoard on onStart() method of the fragment and hiding it on onStop() method.

Problem is KeyBoard is showing when I open fragment for the first time, if I am going back and open that fragment again it is not showing the KeyBoard

```
fun hideKeyboard() {
        val view = this.currentFocus
        if (view != null) {
            val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }

fun showKeyBoard() {
        val view = this.currentFocus
        if (view != null) {
            val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
        }
}
```

Comment: remove that  showKeyBoard() from onStart
() and put that in onResume()

Comment: check if onCreateview is called whenever you open the fragment. If yes then put your showKeyBoard method in onCreateView

Comment: It is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you pass the view you are requesting the keyboard, and an adaptation to it using extension function is

```
fun AppCompatActivity.hideKeyboard(view: View?) {
    view?.let {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}

fun AppCompatActivity.showKeyBoard(view: View?) {
    view?.let  {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
    }
}
```

this is a workable solution but i really don't know why with current Focus doesnt work. I will edit this post again later if I find out why.

**EDIT 1:**

I got the real problem.

when your start your keyboard using `toggleSoftInputFromWindow` your **IMM** holds a reference from window. So if you `requestFocus()`, the IMM understand that the view inside that window already was focused, therefore when you request again using `toggleSoftInputFromWindow()` your IMM will not display the keyboard since "your view already is focused". This problem will happen even you call clearFocus when destroy your fragment. To solve this problem, you can open your keyboard without any window using `toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)`.

```
fun AppCompatActivity.showKeyBoard(view: View?) {
    view?.let  {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
    }
}
```

The flow now is:

open your fragment -> tell for your edit text get focus -> open your keyboard using that new way

close your fragment -> close keyboard with that normal way -> be happy

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is working fine, please upvote this